# jax-ws: reusing stand alone class in list (Cannot cast to ...)

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws

I'm trying to unmarshal an xml packet that looks something like this:

```
    <response>
       <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
       <meetings>
          <meeting>
             <meetingID>test01</meetingID>
             <meetingName>Test</meetingName>
             <createTime>1315254777880</createTime>
             <attendeePW>ap</attendeePW>
             <moderatorPW>mp</moderatorPW>
             <hasBeenForciblyEnded>false</hasBeenForciblyEnded>
             <running>true</running>
          </meeting>
       </meetings>
    </response>
```

However, the meeting element can also be requested individually

```
    <response>
       <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
       <meetingName>Test</meetingName>
       <meetingID>test01</meetingID>
       <createTime>1315254777880</createTime>
       <voiceBridge>70775</voiceBridge>
        <messageKey/>
       <message/>
    </response>
```

I want to reuse one meeting class to server both purposes:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public abstract class BBBBase {
        @XmlElement
        private String returncode,messageKey,message;

    @XmlRootElement(name="response")
    public class BBBMeeting extends BBBBase{
        @XmlElement
        private String voiceBridge, meetingName, meetingID, attendeePW,moderatorPW;

    @XmlRootElement(name="response")
    public class BBBMeetings  extends BBBBase{

        @XmlElementWrapper(name="meetings")
        @XmlElement(name="meeting")
        private List<BBBMeeting> meetings;
```

When I leave the @XmlRootElement on BBBMeeting, unmarshalling BBBMeetings results in an exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: nl.project.response.BBBMeeting cannot be cast to nl.project.response.BBBMeetings

When I remove it, I can unmarshal BBBMeetings fine, but I can no longer unmarshal BBBMeeting.

A workaround would be to create a base BBBMeeting class with a concrete implementation class annotated with @XmlRootElement. But this just seems inelegant to me. I would think that the @XmlElement annotation at 
private List meetings; 
would override any class level annotations for that class, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Are you doing the unmarshalling directly using `Unmarshaller`?  If so you can use an `unmarshal` method that takes a `Class` parameter to specify the type of object you are unmarshalling.